# How to correctly use lookup, vlookup, for my data AND how to count unique lookup's only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to find the total cost of a strategy by looking up the item's nomenclature from a table of unique items matched to a cost.

Also: If an item is in the strategy twice I only want to count the cost once. So strategy 1 would be the cost of Name 1, Name 5, Name 12 and Name 14.

I've played around with this for ages trying various combinations of index match, lookup, and sumif but haven't quite cracked it.

[image]

```
Items    Cost
Nomen1   10
Nomen2   12
Nomen3   15
```

```
Strategy1:

Nomenclature   Cost
Nomen1         =?
Nomen2         =?
               Total Cost
```

```
Strategy2:

Nomenclature    Cost
Nomen3          =?
Nomen12         =?
                Total Cost
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. For a lookup to work, the lookup items must be spelled exactly the same. In your list of items there is no space after the `name`. Yet in your strategy lists there are items with a space after the `name`. Excel will recognize these as different, NOT a match. For example; `Name7` and `Name 7` are not the same because Excel recognizes the space as a character. Also, you need to share with us the formula you are working with. We are not here to do it for you.

Comment: Add some more work of what you've tried so that we can see where you are failing. Then we can point out where you are failing. As it starts, you want someone to look at this messy data that isn't organized properly as Charlie noted, and do it for you. Put more effort in your presentation and show your work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found for you is using a pivot table. You select all the data under items and cost (including items and cost) as data for you pivot table. Then use items as report filter and sum of cost as sigma-values. Then you can use the filter to check all the name's you want and you will get the sum of all those values. Pivot table also has the advantage that it count's every name only once.